# Android service is not starting

Tags: java, android

I need to start a background service on click of android app icon.
Below is my Activity oncreate() method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_executable_runner);

    startService(new Intent(this, ExeRunnerService.class));
}
```

And this is my overridden service class rest all is the default.

```
public class ExeRunnerService extends Service{
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;

}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service Running");
        }
    });
    th.start();

}
}
```

I don't have any initialization code for the same.
But when I start the application I am not getting any service logs.

Comment: execCommandLine has any kind of while loop to avoid it finishing? If not, it'll run once then finish ergo stop the Service

Comment: Show your full service code, or at least the important parts. IntentService is easier to use than normal Service, so you should do that.

Comment: You started two threads twice, dude.

Comment: Service inside another thread? This is never advisable. A very bad way. Remove the thread inside 'onCreate()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put and override on the onStartCommand, and call a super.onCreate() in the overridden onCreate method;

Like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static boolean isRunning = false;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
}

public static boolean isServiceRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;

    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Iv added the isRunning flag because I have often experienced that my service is already running and initializing objects again then is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is calling but problem is with thread replace your code with following code in service's on create method

```
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.d("Run", "Service Running");
     new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            Log.d("Run", "Service Running");
        }
    }).start();;

}
```